# Select hours as columns from Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with an Oracle database table that is structured like this:

```
TRANS_DATE      TRANS_HOUR_ENDING      TRANS_HOUR_SUFFIX        READING
1/1/2021        1                      1                        100
1/1/2021        2                      1                        105
...             ...                    ...                      ...
1/1/2021        24                     1                        115
```

The TRANS_HOUR_SUFFIX is only used to track hourly readings on days where day light savings time ends (when there could be 2 hours with the same TRANS_HOUR value). This column is the bane of this database's design, however I'm trying to do something to select this data in a certain way. We need a report that columnizes this data based on the hour. Therefore, it would be structured like this (last day shows a day on which DST would end):

```
TRANS_DATE      HOUR_1    HOUR_2_1    HOUR_2_2   ...    HOUR_24
1/1/2021        100       105         0          ...    115
1/2/2021        112       108         0          ...    135
...             ...       ...         ...        ...    ...
11/7/2021       117       108         107        ...    121
```

I have done something like this before with a PIVOT, however in this case I'm having trouble determining what I should do to account for the suffix. When DST ending happens, we have to account for this hour. I know that we can do this by selecting each hourly value individually with decode or case statements, but that is some messy code. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Instead of adding extra columns, could you instead add an extra row that only had two hours populated?  Something like '11/7/2021 - 1' and '11/7/2021 - 2'? That would let you use the suffix as part of the implicit `GROUP BY` in your `PIVOT`

Answer (score 0):

You can include multiple source columns in the pivot `for()` and `in()` clauses, so you could do:

```
select *
from (
  select trans_date,
    trans_hour_ending,
    trans_hour_suffix,
    reading
  from your_table
)
pivot (max(reading) for (trans_hour_ending, trans_hour_suffix)
  in ((1, 1) as hour_1, (2, 1) as hour_2_1, (2, 2) as hour_2_2, (3, 1) as hour_3,
    -- snip
    (23, 1) as hour_23, (24, 1) as hour_24))
order by trans_date;
```

where every hour has a `(24, 1)` tuple, and the DST-relevant hour has an extra `(2, 2)` tuple.

If you don't have rows for every hour - which you don't appear to have form the very brief sample data, at least for suffix 2 for non-DST days - then you will get null results for those, but can replace them with zeros:

```
select trans_date,
  coalesce(hour_1, 0) as hour_1,
  coalesce(hour_2_1, 0) as hour_2_1,
  coalesce(hour_2_2, 0) as hour_2_2,
  coalesce(hour_3, 0) as hour_3,
  -- snip
  coalesce(hour_23, 0) as hour_23,
  coalesce(hour_24, 0) as hour_24
from (
  select trans_date,
    trans_hour_ending,
    trans_hour_suffix,
    reading
  from your_table
)
pivot (max(reading) for (trans_hour_ending, trans_hour_suffix)
  in ((1, 1) as hour_1, (2, 1) as hour_2_1, (2, 2) as hour_2_2, (3, 1) as hour_3,
    -- snip
    (23, 1) as hour_23, (24, 1) as hour_24))
order by trans_date;
```

which with slightly expanded sample data gets:

```
TRANS_DATE     HOUR_1   HOUR_2_1   HOUR_2_2     HOUR_3    HOUR_23    HOUR_24
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2021-01-01        100        105          0          0          0        115
2021-01-02        112        108          0          0          0        135
2021-11-07        117        108        107          0          0        121
```

Which is a bit long-winded when you have to include all 25 columns everywhere; but to avoid that you'd have to do a dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, if you can format it with an additional row, I would recommend just having a row for the extra hour.  Every other day would look normal.  The query to do it would look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE READINGS
(
  TRANS_DATE DATE,
  TRANS_HOUR INTEGER,
  TRANS_SUFFIX INTEGER,
  READING INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO readings
  SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 1, 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 2, 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('11/07/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 1, 1, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('11/07/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 1, 2, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('11/07/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 2, 1, 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('11/07/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 2, 2, 350 FROM DUAL;

SELECT TRANS_DATE||DECODE(MAX(TRANS_SUFFIX) OVER (PARTITION BY TRANS_DATE), 1, NULL, 2, ' - '||TRANS_SUFFIX) AS TRANS_DATE,
       HOUR_1, HOUR_2, /*...*/ HOUR_24
FROM readings 
PIVOT (MAX(READING) FOR TRANS_HOUR IN (1 AS HOUR_1, 2 AS HOUR_2, /*...*/ 24 AS HOUR_24));
```

This would result in the following results (Sorry, I can't get dbfiddle to work):

| TRANS_DATE | HOUR_1 | HOUR_2 | HOUR_24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-21 | 100 | 100 | - |
| 07-NOV-21 - 1 | 200 | 500 | - |
| 07-NOV-21 - 2 | 300 | 350 | - |